# String comparison with changed character ordering

Tags: c++, c, string, comparison

How would you compare strings when the characters `(` and `)` should come after the alphanumeric characters. Do I have to write a function or is there any library function available?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: actually I'm comparing std::string but a C function would be of help (maybe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::lexicographical_compare` with a custom predicate. That predicate should take 2 chars, and return false if the first should come before the second.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built in way to do this. You'll have to write your own comparison function/functor. I believe you can however implement this with character traits so that `operator<` still works, but you won't be using `std::string` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy both strings that are to be compared to temporary strings
2. In both strings, replace `(` and `)` with characters that come after alphanumeric characters *in the particular encoding* you're using
3. Compare the manipulated results with standard library comparing function
4. Use the result of function and dispose of the manipulated strings

For instance, `(` and `)` come before alphanumeric characters in ASCII, but `{` and `}` come after!

Answer (score 0):

some environments have provision for custom collation sequences, but generally speaking you have to write your own.